# Bash Getting output of command into variable

Tags: bash, jq

I have JSON file named input.json wich contains following data

```
{
 "Data": {
   "Info": [
     {
       "tranID": "1",
       "architecture": "thread_1",
       "build": "110",
       "win": "450"
     },
     {
       "tranID": "2",
       "architecture": "thread_2",
       "build": "120",
       "win": "455"
     }
   ]
 }
}
```

Here I want to write function which will get file name as input parameter and now inside function I want to read last Object array and two fields from which  **build** and **win** ans stor there values is variable ex **total**  which will contain addition of **build** and **win**  and insert this value again inside JSON .

so that final JSON will look like

```
 {
  "Data": {
    "Info": [
      {
        "tranID": "1",
        "architecture": "thread_1",
        "build": "110",
        "win": "450"
      },
      {
        "tranID": "2",
        "architecture": "thread_2",
        "build": "120",
        "win": "455",
       "total": "575"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have tried reading initial JSON build fiels and tried to store it in variable just printed that variable but variable is not stroing that value it's coming empty .

```
varr =  $jq '.Data.Info[-1].build' ${1}
echo $varr
```

also tried

```
varr=$(echo $jq '.Data.Info[-1].build' ${1})
echo $varr
```

echo not printing value

where ${1} is my input JSON file

Comment: If `jq '.Data.Info[-1].build' ${1}` is the command you've already found to be working, then `varr=$(jq '.Data.Info[-1].build' ${1})` with no echo or anything

Comment: Don't you hate it when a question is closed as you're about to hit submit on an answer... This should help you get started: `jq '.Data.Info[-1] as $last | .Data.Info[-1].total = (($last.build | tonumber) + ($last.win | tonumber) | tostring)' input.json` -- basically, do all the math and such *in* `jq`. Save its output to a temporary file and then `mv` that back to your original.

Comment: Lots of bugs here around inadequate quoting, BTW. Might make a habit of running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ before asking questions here.

Comment: Thank You for help